# PDF of Normal Distribution

Tags: probability

I know that this must be quite a trivial question to answer, but I'm a bit confused as to how the PDF for a distribution works.

Consider the Normal Distribution. We know that the PDF of a Normal Distribution with mean 0 and variance 1 is $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{\frac{1}{2}}$

So, plugging in x=1 we get 0.24197

Given that the normal distribution is continuous, I thought that the probability of a single value was 0?

Comment: densities don't give probabilities directly; integrating densities over sets gives the probabilities of those sets. The integral over a single point (with respect to Lebesgue measure) is always zero.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The probability of a single value *is* zero.

You can interpret the density as the probability at $x$ that you lie within some small interval around $x$ normalized by the size of the interval. $f(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{ P( x- \frac{\epsilon}{2} \leq X \leq x+  \frac{\epsilon}{2})}{\epsilon}$, or $ P( x- \frac{\epsilon}{2} \leq X \leq x+  \frac{\epsilon}{2}) \approx \epsilon f(x)$. But $P(X=x) = 0$.

See section 3.2 of [these notes](https://courses.engr.illinois.edu/ece313/notes_webpage.html) for more details.

Comment: thanks. So why will `dnorm(1)` in R output 0.2419707. You're saying that it calculates it for a very small interval around x?

Comment: Most likely it just plugs into $f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2 \pi \sigma^2}} e^{-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2 \sigma^2}}$. I'm saying you can approximate the probability that your RV is between $1-\epsilon/2$ and $1+\epsilon/2$ as $\epsilon f_X(1)$ for small $\epsilon$. The density in density function is similar to the description in physics -- a table has mass (which is analogous to probability). but its mass (probability) per volume (length of interval) is density -- each point contains no mass (but has density), but the table itself has mass.

Comment: I see, thanks for that analogy.

Answer (score 0):

Usually we say, for example, the probability that the value is between $-0.1$ and $0.1$ is
$$\int_{-0.1}^{0.1}f(x)dx$$
and if we take a single point
$$\int_1^1f(x)dx=0.$$
It is the integral of the PDF that gives us the probability, not the value.